# Boosting Starts with and contains search using Elastic/NEST

Tags: c#, nest, elasticsearch

I am doing a wildcard search as below and I want to have the starts with(her*) results to have more ranking than the contains(*her*) search results. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
elasticClient.Search<ClientSearchContract>(p => 
                p.Query(q => q
                    .Bool(bq => bq
                        .Should(mq => mq.QueryString(qs =>
                    qs.Query(her* *her*))
                        )
                    )
                )
                .Sort(x => x.OnField("_score").Descending())
            );
```

Comment: why don't u use 2 query containers and boost them differently ?

Comment: i also don't see the field that you are querying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that could help you :

```
            var result = elasticClient.Search<ClientSearchContract>(q => q
            .Index("index")
            .Type("type")
            .Query(qq =>
            {
                QueryContainer startsQuery = null;
                QueryContainer containQuery = null;
                {
                    startsQuery |= qq.QueryString(qs => qs.OnFields(f => f.Field).Query("her*").Boost(2));
                    containQuery |= qq.QueryString(qs => qs.OnFields(f => f.Field).Query("*her*").Boost(1.2));
                }

                return startsQuery || containQuery;
            })
            .Take(10)
            .Sort(x => x.OnField("_score").Descending())
            );
```

Comment: Thanks @dzomba for your answer. With this, I get the search results appear better than before. Is there a way we can boost those starts with search results if it matches only the first word but not the words appear in between?

Comment: Thanks @dzomba for your answer. With this, I get the search results appear better than before. Is there a way we can boost those starts with search results if query text matches only the first word of the matching sentence but not the words appear in between.

Comment: hmm i don;t think that is possible

Answer (score 0):

We use [custom score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-custom-score-query.html) scripts for this purpose. In JSON it looks like this:

```
"query": 
{
    "custom_score": 
    { 
        "query": *query* ,
        "params" : 
        { 
            "streetMultiply": " + ((!searchQuery.HasCityValue()) ? 100 : 0) + @",
            "addressMultiply": " + ((!searchQuery.HasStreetValue()) ? 100 : 0) + @"
        }
        ,"script": "if (doc['streetId'].value == 0) { _score * streetMultiply } else { if (doc['addressId'].value == 0) { _score * addressMultiply } else { _score } }"
    } 
}, "size": 100 }"
```

We don't use NEST for this, but I've found a [pull-requst](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/pull/237) for implementation this in NEST

Comment: Thanks for your reply @backs. It seems 'custom score' is absolete from v1.1 and there is one called 'custom filter score' but it doesn't seem to work with wildcards as filtering can be done only on terms?

Comment: @SantoshAchanta we are now upgrading our elastic search and NEST, so I'll tell you results, how we fixed this problem

Comment: Cool, keen to hear from you. :)